# CSS Border Width Effecting Width of PHP Form

Tags: php, html, css

I have a PHP form which I created using a tabbed box. There are 3 tabs, each tab requires the user to enter values for a varied amount of fields. I then continued to add a border around the form headings, tabs and the form itself. The border appears fine but its width is the entire width of the page. Whereas, my form only takes up 50% of the width. I know how to change the width and all that, which I already did but the problem is if I change the width of the border, the width of the form is effected. At the moment I can change the width of the border to about 70% without effecting the form, but anymore than that and the form is ruined; I am using CSS within the style tags of my HTML page as follows;

This CSS code is for the tabs themselves and also the tabbed area where the form is located;

```
.tabs { list-style: none; }
.tabs li { display: inline; }
.tabs li a { color: black; float: left; display: block; padding: 4px 10px; margin-left: -1px; position: relative; left: 1px; background: #D8D8D8; text-decoration: none; }
.tabs li a:hover { background: #ccc; }

.group:after { visibility: hidden; display: block; font-size: 0; content: " "; clear: both; height: 0; }

.box-wrap { position: relative; min-height: 250px;  }
.tabbed-area div div { background: white; padding: 10px; min-height: 250px; position: absolute; top: -1px; left: 40px; width: 50%; background-color: #D8D8D8; }
.tabbed-area div div, .tabs li a { border: 1px solid #0000FF; }

#box-one:target, #box-two:target, #box-three:target {
  z-index: 1;
}
```

This is the CSS for the border (if I change the width to anything lower than 1600px, the form is effected);

```
.border {
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: medium;
    height: 750px;
    background-color: #F2F2F2;
    width: 1600px;

}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated thanks!

Comment: can you post relevant rendered HTML code and CSS code on http://jsbin.com

Comment: +1, it's hard to help on CSS issues without a testing environment.

Comment: its a good idea to upload some html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `max-width: 300px;` and if that doesn't work, `max-width: 300px !important;` to override any existing stylings for that box.

Else, provide samples on jsbin.com as Kheema Pandey suggested and we could work it out.